# Can I publish an image and some text to a News Feed or Timeline without pre-approval if I have publish_action permission?

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make an app (installed by a user) that will post updates to their Facebook account. I am more than happy to get permission from the user to do this, use the Graph API and do server side elements if needed. Sadly I am utterly confused by the the deprecated Facebook features and documentation.

1. Can I publish an image and some text to a News Feed or Timeline without pre-approval for each individual publish event, when I already have publish_action permission?
2. In what fields would I be able to place the text? ('message' and 'comment' fields do not seem to be allowed)
3. Can I put text in the image, or do images need pre-approval before posting as well?

Edit: Not sure why the question got down voted? Even though the intent behind my question might not be allowed (as it now turns out), it's still a valid question that needed clarification.

Answer: Okay, this might have seemed obvious to some, but not to me. Facebook documentation is very poor indeed. So, it's impossible to post to somebodies Facebook (timeline, wall, etc.) if they do not give permission while they review each post. You can however ask for their login credentials only once and keep this for as many postings as you like, but all this does is avoid the need for the user to log into facebook after they approve each of the posts.

Addition: It might look like others are posting to facebook pages without asking individual permission each time. But I have now learnt that this is when a user has chosen to follow a Facebook page. Each time the page posts to it's own page the message is also repeated on the person's Facebook page (without pre-approval).

Comment: Auto-posting is not allowed in general. If you make posts in the name of a user, then under normal circumstances each and every single post should actively triggered by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can 
for photo :

```
 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                                .setBitmap(yourSelectedImage)
                                .setCaption(yourPhotoCaption)
                                .build();
 SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                            .addPhoto(photo)
                            .build();

 ShareApi.share(content,fbResponseCallback);
```

for status update :

```
  Bundle parameters=new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("message",message);

  final GraphRequest request=new GraphRequest(
                                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                "/me/feed",
                                parameters,
                                HttpMethod.POST,
                                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) { /// Your actions here});
```

This would be successfull only after you have publish permissions and also on test accounts

Comment: That's good news. But I'm still very confused. How does pre-filling a message in a 'status update' avoid violating the 'do not pre-fill the message' requirement in the Facebook policy?

Comment: its simply mean user should input what he wants ,app should not put anything on users behalf

Comment: so , if u have an edittext field where user enters his status update, and u then take this text to upload , that will be ok with fb, but if you put content by urself that will violate its policy

Comment: Okay, reading the manner in which I wrote my question I guess I wasn't totally clear. I have an app that is running as a background service that doesn't have any user interface. I wish this service to post to the user's Facebook while they are doing an activity during which they are not allowed to interact with their mobile device (such as being on the bosses time or doing surgery). Is there any way of publishing something about what they are doing (while they are doing it) without them creating the photo or typing the message themself?

Comment: see how you get the input is totally upto u ,fb only says you can not interfere and put content by urself ,so as long as by any method you are getting content from user , fb wont have any problem with it. FYI you have to submit your application ,fb guys test how and when you take the content from user and how would that appear on fb . They grant you permission only if u adhere to their policy, Hence getting content and posting to fb are two different process independent of each other ,so my answer solves ur 2nd issue

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, they way you are stating it seems to be more explicite than Facebook seems to be stating it. For example, when reading the documentation 'message', 'comment' and 'photo' fields are restricted to user input only, but 'description' and 'picture' fields are not? I could also automatically generate an Open Graph Story on a server and only publish a link using the 'link' field without a message or comment attached (as this does not seem to have the restriction either).

Comment: yes u stated right,lets consider a example,where user types "love" and you have an AI , that finds something relavant to it , that you can attach in the fields u mentioned,but those would be useless until user puts the mandatory fields by himself,in case of status , u cant automate the status message,but as u said u can automate few fields related to it except the mandatory fields

Comment: Aha, if there are mandatory fields this changes the situation. Which ones are mandatory? Because reading the Graph API documentation and using the Graph API Explorer it is possible to publish items without having the 'comment', 'message' and 'photo' fields. (For example: Post/v2.8//me/feed with a link and a picture.) So technically it's possible to publish something without the user entering the information. The Graph API Explorer does not verify for mandatory fields and technically I'm not breaking the rules of the policy. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130527/discussion-between-simmy-and-ak9637).